# VBScript to open Excel then add a VBA macro

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I need a VBScript to open a certain Excel Document, then when open it must add a Macro and save.

I can open the Excel document but I do not know how to open the Macro screen(<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>) and then add the code and save...

Is there anyway to do this?

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Visible = True`

'Macro Script

Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range   
    For Each cell In Range("H1:W200")
        If Not isEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value = 0 Then 
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                Columns("H").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("I").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("M").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("N").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("P").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("Q").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("S").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("T").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                Columns("V").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537810/vbscript-to-write-a-macro-within-an-excel-file

Comment: I strongly advise you to solve this without SendKeys, since this approach can be (unwillingly) sabotaged by the user, and also renders the screen useless for the duration. [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/194611) or @Zam's link should help you.

Answer (score 2):

Follow these steps:

1. Open the VBA Editor in Excel and add a new Module.
2. Paste your macro code into it.
3. Right-click the Module and choose `Export...`.
4. Give it a filename and save it somewhere.
5. In your VBScript, add the following lines of code:

   ```
   objWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Import "/path/to/your/module.bas"
   objWorkbook.Save
   ```

   Note that, in Excel 2007+, you can't save macros in `xlsx` files. You'll need to use `SaveAs` instead and give the file an `xslm` extension. Or, you can use the old `xls` format (which is what you appear to be using from your example).

Answer (score 0):

You can add code programmatically by using the `VBComponents` object of the `VBProject` object. So add this behind the last line of your code:

```
Set objModule = objworkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)       ' 1 = vbext_ct_StdModule

objExcel.Visible = True    ' not necessary if you close Excel anyway

theSource = ""
theSource = theSource & "Sub HideRows()" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "    Dim cell As Range   " & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "    For Each cell In Range(""H1:W200"")" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "        If Not isEmpty(cell) Then" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "            If cell.Value <> """" And cell.Value = 0 Then " & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""H"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""I"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""J"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""M"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""N"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""O"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""P"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""Q"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""S"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""T"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "                Columns(""V"").EntireColumn.Hidden = True" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "            End If" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "        End If" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "    Next" & vbCrLf
theSource = theSource & "End Sub" & vbCrLf

objModule.CodeModule.AddFromString theSource

'objExcel.Quit

'Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not straight forward, but what I would do is use `SendKeys` function to simulate <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>.

```
Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True
```

Then using the same logic, use keystrokes to navigate to the proper window, adding a module, then paste the macro code in the right place using:

```
Application.SendKeys ""^V"
Application.SendKeys ""^V", True   'Incase that one above does not work
```

Then you could save using:

```
Application.SendKeys ""^S", True
```

You can read more about that [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/491867-visual-basic-applications-close-visual-basic-applications-editor-window.html) and [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/519771-sendkeys-%5Ev-copy-excel-outlook.html)

But another way is to use a mouse and keyboard macro recorder (stand alone application that can be programmed to mimic actions). I personally have used [KeyText](http://download.canadiancontent.net/KeyText.html) for more than 10 years to do that sort of thing.

Comment: Just to mention: many people regard SendKeys as too risky, and generally do not recommend using it for a business solution.