# vbscript to add macro to MS Word

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, macros

I have the following VBscript ( [based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537810/vbscript-to-write-a-macro-within-an-excel-file) ):

```
Set wdApp = CreateObject( "Word.Application" )
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open( "c:\docs_to_process\document1.docx" )
Set xlmodule = wdDoc.VBProject.VBComponents.Add( 1 )
strCode = _
    "sub test()" & vbCr & _
    "   msgbox ""Inside the macro"" " & vbCr & _
    "end sub"
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString strCode
wdDoc.Save
wdDoc.Close
wdApp.Quit
```

The problem is: when I run it and stop the script before saving the document, I can see the macro in the opened Word file, but when I process futher, save the document and quit the script, after that if I open Word document, I see no macro in it.

What am I doing wrong?

p.s: i've provide fixed strings here for anybody else faced with same issue:

```
wdDoc.SaveAs "c:\docs_to_process\document1.docm", 13
wdDoc.Close
```

**important note:**
instead of just save, give document new name and point 
document type as *wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled* it is 13 in enum list
I don't know why, but pointing enum type as

```
wdDoc.SaveAs "c:\docs_to_process\document1.docm", wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled
```

causes same error after opening file as if i just change extention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For macro the file extension should be docm i.e. macro enabled. So change the file name

wdDoc.SaveAs "c:\docs_to_process\document1.docm", wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled

Comment: got it, thanks for pointing direction, and what if word document previously had no macro and my one is the first to insert? I tried to save it just with ".docm" extention but after that - Word application tells that document has errors, should i somehow enable macro in vbscript while processing .docx file?

Comment: In such case read the file as docx. Add the macro and do SaveAs

Comment: Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open( "c:\docs_to_process\document1.docx" )
wdDoc.SaveAs("c:\docs_to_process\document1.docm") - gives an error when i try to open .docm file
looks like i had to do some actions with file converter, but i can't find proper information for VBS not VBA

Comment: Updated the answer to do saveas

Comment: i've replaced wdFormatXMLDocumentMacroEnabled with it's enum index (13) - now it works like a charm, thank You for Your time!